# Is COM a requirement for WTL?

Tags: winapi, com, atl, wtl

In every WTL example, `CoInitialize` is called as the first function of `WinMain`. I know that WTL is based on ATL, which is closely related to COM, but as I see it, a WTL program can easily not use any COM code (can't it?).

What adds to the confusion is that ATL has classes such as `CComCriticalSection`, which has nothing to do with COM, despite the name.

So my question is: is it necessary to call `CoInitialize` in a WTL program, even when no COM is explicitly used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `CoInitialize` is not a requirement for a WTL application. Many WTL classes are unrelated to COM. Historically, as you mentioned, WTL was tightly connected to ATL, which in turn was a primary framework for COM development, and COM initialization was a natural step because the application was likely to do something with COM anyway.

Comment: Certain shell components may require `CoInitialize`/`CoInitializeEx` as well.